# java generics and program-design, how to properly implement a list which contains subtypes of superclass?

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, collections

I have an animal class and some actual animals like mouse, horse ... which are expending the class animal. Now I want to create a class population. A population has a list containing only one kind of animal.

I can run this approach, but it is rather ugly. With wildcards `<? extends Animal>` I don't need any casts, but adding another animal won't work. When I just use `<Animal>`, I always have to cast and I would have to write methods for every kind of animal for example `add_mouse()`, altough all of these methods would do nearly the same.

My first thougt was to introduce a population class for every kind of animal, but that wouldn't be a good solution either.

I kindly ask you for help. Is there a proper way it can be done or could you suggest me another program-design please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I already use a List, but I a have problems with the inheritance and generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an upper-bounded type variable on your `Population` class, and a `List` inside that class constrained to contain only instances of that type variable:

```
class Population<A extends Animal> {
  final List<A> animals = new ArrayList<>();

  void add(A animal) {
    animals.add(animal);
  }
}
```

Then you can use it some like this:

```
Population<Dog> dogs = new Population<>();
dogs.add(new Dog());  // OK.

Population<Cat> cats = new Population<>();
cats.add(new Cat());  // OK.

dogs.add(new Cat());  // Compiler error.
cats.add(new Dog());  // Compiler error.
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: When an answer resolves your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Of course, but I had to wait for several minutes. Now I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask another question. This works great when I call add from the outside, but what can I do when I want do call add() inside the population class?

Comment: You call `add(animal)` (or `this.add(animal)`). It's no different from outside the class: you can only invoke that method with a reference to `A` or literal null.

Comment: I have already tried this but got an compiler-error. In the constructor of Population I want to add animals to the List. At this place the compiler don't know that it is a cat Population for example (neither I). Outside, in your example, this was fully clear. It would be good when I can do something like add(new A()), but unfortunately this isn't possible.

Comment: "In the constructor of Population I want to add animals to the List" The only way you can do this is to pass in a `List<A> animalsToAdd` (or `List<? extends A> animalsToAdd`), and then add these to the list. You can't create `A` instances in your class because `A` is unknown.

Comment: Thanks again. Just if you are interested: My solution was to wrap some of the Population functionality into a new Controller class for population. In this class I can now add animals the way you suggested.